# Run over remote files quickly using python?

Tags: python, paramiko, remote-server

I have several large files stored on a remote server that I would like to run over using a local Python script. I am aware that I can use `paramiko` in Python to open them and run over them that way, but it is much too slow. Also, `ftp`ing the files over is not an option since they are too large. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Would running the application remotely be an option?

Comment: Perhaps. If I ran the application from the remote server, would it be able to access the local version of Python and all it's libraries (Python is not available on the remote server)?

Comment: You either have to copy the data from the remote server to your local system, or you need to install Python on the remote system and run your code there.  Those are really the only two options without substantial architectural changes: e.g., choose an implementation language other than Python that is available on the remote server, etc.

Comment: Thanks, larsks. I figured as much, but thought it couldn't hurt to ask.